# @Contract and throwing exceptions

Tags: java, intellij-idea

If I have some simple code:

```
public int doSomething(final String str)
{
  try
  {
    return Integer.parseInt(str);
  }
  catch (final NumberFormatException e)
  {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Bad");
  }
}
```

Everything is good, but if I want to take the exception creation and move it to it's own method:

```
public int doSomethingElse(final String str)
{
try
  {
    return Integer.parseInt(str);
  }
  catch (final NumberFormatException e)
  {
    doThrow();
  }
}

public void doThrow()
{
  throw new IllegalArgumentException("Bad");
}
```

then the code no longer compiles in IntelliJ because it does not understand that `doThrow()` will always throw an exception and so complains that in that path there is no return value.

It seems to me that this is the type of thing which IntelliJ contracts were set up for, but if I attempt to add the `@Contract("_ -> fail")` annotation to `doThrow()` it doesn't help.  How can I make this work (short of adding a `return null` after the call to `doThrow()`, which is ugly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Java compiler knows nothing of the JetBrains attributes like `@Contract`.  IntelliJ may know that `doThrow()` always throws, but the compiler does not, so this is not well-formed code.

In cases like this, I have a utility method that I use:

```
public final class ContractUtilities {
    public static IllegalStateException unreachable() {
        return new IllegalStateException("Code is supposed to be unreachable.");
    }
    // ...
}
```

...and I add a theoretically unreachable `throw` statement like so:

```
public int doSomethingElse(final String str) {
    try {
        return Integer.parseInt(str);
    }
    catch (final NumberFormatException e) {
        doThrow();
        throw ContractUtilities.unreachable();
    }
}
```

You could also simply make `doThrow()` return the exception to be thrown:

```
public int doSomethingElse(final String str) {
    try {
        return Integer.parseInt(str);
    }
    catch (final NumberFormatException e) {
        throw doThrow();
    }
}
```

Comment: The second solution here is a good one for me, I'll use that.  Thanks!